# Error: Forbiddenat SendStream.error

Tags: node.js, static, express

When adding static folder app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));  I am getting error 
Error: Forbiddenat SendStream.error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known issue https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1229.

Quick fix is to use app.use(express.static( __dirname + '\\static'));

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem, but I just encountered this error message when trying to server files with names like "./foo.txt". Running `fs.realpathSync()` first resolved the issue. (It occurred even with the most recent Express)

Comment: I'm having the same issue using `gulp-connect`. Are they related?

Comment: This issue is related for express on windows. Also it is fixed in latest version so I would like to recommend upgrade to latest stable version.

Comment: for gulp-connect use `root: [__dirname]` or `root: require('path').resolve('./')` to fix this error: https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/54