# 403 / Forbidden on favicon with NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, express, favicon, http-status-code-403, locomotivejs

I'm currently testing [LocomotiveJS](http://www.locomotivejs.org) and have a very simple "hello world" app up

I thought I'd set up the connect favicon middleware, but when I visit any route ('/' for example) I get the following in the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Tue, 17 Jul 2012 21:41:25 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
Error: Forbidden
    at SendStream.error (/Users/alex/Desktop/LocoTest/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:142:16)
    at SendStream.pipe (/Users/alex/Desktop/LocoTest/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:307:52)
    at Object.static (/Users/alex/Desktop/LocoTest/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:78:8)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:219:24)
    at Router._dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:5)
    at Object.middleware [as handle] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/locomotive/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at multipart (/Users/alex/Desktop/LocoTest/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:52:61)
    at module.exports (/Users/alex/Desktop/LocoTest/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9)
127.0.0.1 - - [Tue, 17 Jul 2012 21:41:25 GMT] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520133/error-forbiddenat-sendstream-error ? (a recent bug in express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the send middleware is [considering this request malicious](https://github.com/ritch/send/blob/master/lib/send.js#L307) because it's not the root and contains "..". I'm not sure why `/favicon.ico` would cause isMalicious to return `true` though. I'd suggest debugging into `isMalicious` and examining `this._root` and `this.path`. Could either be some bug in `send` or `favicon` middleware or perhaps your code isn't configuring them. Can't help with that unless you post some code.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Express and Connect were pulled in as dependencies?  I encountered a bug with express@3.0.0beta6, which I think has been fixed in beta7 (though I haven't confirmed that myself).  I'm running on express@3.0.0beta4, which I know works, and you can revert to that by doing:

```
$ npm uninstall express
$ npm install express@3.0.0beta4
```

The master branch of Locomotive is using the Express 3.x betas, which have generally been pretty solid.  I'm looking forward to that being stable, and pushing out new releases.