# Express.js Malicious Path Middleware Error 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I get this error when I make a post request to my server, but only on my production server (pre-release) - my staging server works fine. Both are AWS ubuntu boxes.

Looking through the stack trace, the source of the error is an http request with a url of '../../css', that is then interpreted by send.js 145 and send.js 310 as a malicious path, causing the server to crash. However, after grepping my code base, there are no occurrences of '../../css'.

I would really appreciate any help or insight anyone can offer, as the only similar SO question I found helped me diagnose the malicious path issue, but didn't helping me understand where the ../../css is coming from:

[403 / Forbidden on favicon with NodeJS / Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531381/403-forbidden-on-favicon-with-nodejs-express)

Thanks!

```
{
   "date":"Wed Nov 20 2013 04:16:30 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
   "process":{
      "pid":10842,
      "uid":0,
      "gid":0,
      "cwd":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket",
      "execPath":"/usr/bin/nodejs",
      "version":"v0.10.21",
      "argv":[
         "nodejs",
         "/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/app.js"
      ],

      "memoryUsage":{
         "rss":89632768,
         "heapTotal":63371520,
         "heapUsed":30075536
      }
   },

   "os":{
      "loadavg":[
         0.0029296875,
         0.0146484375,
         0.04541015625
      ],

      "uptime":2938975.002619042
   },

   "trace":[
      {
         "column":16,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js",
         "function":"SendStream.error",
         "line":145,
         "method":"error",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":52,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js",
         "function":"SendStream.pipe",
         "line":310,
         "method":"pipe",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":8,
         "file":"[as handle] (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js",
         "function":"Object.staticMiddleware",
         "line":84,
         "method":"staticMiddleware",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":15,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js",
         "function":"next",
         "line":190,
         "method":null,
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":5,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js",
         "function":"Object.logger",
         "line":156,
         "method":"logger",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":15,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js",
         "function":"next",
         "line":190,
         "method":null,
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":7,
         "file":"[as handle] (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/favicon.js",
         "function":"Object.favicon",
         "line":77,
         "method":"favicon",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":15,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js",
         "function":"next",
         "line":190,
         "method":null,
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":5,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js",
         "function":"Object.logger",
         "line":156,
         "method":"logger",
         "native":false
      },

      {
         "column":15,
         "file":"/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js",
         "function":"next",
         "line":190,
         "method":null,
         "native":false
      }
   ],

   "stack":[
      "Error: Forbidden",
      "    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:145:16)",
      "    at SendStream.pipe (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:310:52)",
      "    at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:84:8)",
      "    at next (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)",
      "    at Object.logger (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:156:5)",
      "    at next (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)",
      "    at Object.favicon [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/favicon.js:77:7)",
      "    at next (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)",
      "    at Object.logger (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/logger.js:156:5)",
      "    at next (/home/ubuntu/developer-getlocket/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)"
   ],

   "req":{
      "url":"/../../css",
      "headers":{
         "host":"developers.getlocket.com",
         "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
         "accept":"*/*",
         "cookie":"connect.sid=s%3A9_PUj6XZqF8HKRCoTqHPT5cJ.V2cxTaxk5sLlsNtAMByR7JpvtvwbuebOMZ6IgoEQLgI",
         "connection":"keep-alive",
         "accept-language":"en-us",
         "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7"
      },

      "method":"GET",
      "httpVersion":"1.1",
      **"originalUrl":"/../../css",**
      "query":{

      }
   },

   "level":"error",
   "message":"middlewareError",
   "timestamp":"2013-11-20T04:16:30.958Z"
}
```

Comment: A pre-prod machine that isn't set up the same as a prod machine is a total waste of space...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson as of the last few hours, I totally see why. The issue was solved by uninstalling and reinstalling the nodemodules

Comment: It's amazing how often this mistake is made, almost as often as the I assumed my backup would restore mistake. Been caught out myself once. Imagine if it had only come to light post release....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out the underlying issue, but I did fix it by uninstalling the node_modules and then reinstalling them.