# node.js+express+jade: style.css internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, pug

I have a problem with node.js+express+jade that I don't know how to resolve, I have already searched on google and stackoverflow with no solution, so I ask to you to help me please :)

The problem is that all works except for style.css:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal 
 Server Error)
```

P.S: i have reinstalled latest versions of *node.js* and modules for security, without solution

UPDATE:the error outs ONLY when I add this: `link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')` in the jade file

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express"); 
app = express(),
routes = require('./routes');

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', 8080);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get("/", routes.index);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
    console.log("App listening on port " + app.get("port"));
});
```

**routes/index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
};
```

**public/style.css**

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**i have got this error:**

```
my_path_privacy\nodejs-test>node app.js
    App listening on port 8080
    ←[90mGET / ←[32m200 ←[90m3674ms - 867b←[0m
    TypeError: Object #<SendStream> has no method 'on'
        at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle] (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:89:8)
        at next (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
        at pass (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:110:24)
        at Router._dispatch (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:4)
        at Object.router [as handle] (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
        at next (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
        at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:48:5)
        at next (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
        at Object.urlencoded [as handle] (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencoded.js:41:37)
        at next (my_path_privacy\nodejs-test\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    ←[90mGET /style.css ←[31m500 ←[90m52ms - 1.34kb←[0m
```

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "app-test",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
       "start": "node app.js"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "express": "3.4.7",
      "jade": "1.1.0"
   },
   "engines": {
      "node": "0.10.24",
      "npm": "1.3.21"
  }
}
```

**index.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Hello world
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
  body
    p Hello world
```

Comment: Sounds like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520151/893780) might be able to solve your issue.

Comment: @robertklep: already tried and doesn't resolve but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is related, I had a lot of trouble with embedded script in jade file. Syntax changed. You might have to add a dot to the script tags in jade file, if JS is followed in next lines.

There is another evil change, you need to write doctype html instead of doctype 5

```
script
  var x=1

is now

script.
  var x=1
```

Comment: hmm I have not a script tag in the jade file but I'm looking for syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a templating engine problem, just out of curiosity, can u try sending an array or object instead of the "Hello , World", just replace

```
res.render('index', {title: "Hello, world"});
```

with

```
res.render('index', {title: some array or object here});
```

Comment: usually the wrong or no engine dependencies cause this, might wanna double check that too (package.json)

Comment: look at new updates on the open post, the problem is in the link rel